# How do I import a scss npm module into Ember

Tags: css, ember.js, sass

How do I correctly import a non-plugin npm module into Ember?

I'm trying to use the sass version of [`flag-icon-css`](https://github.com/lipis/flag-icon-css) with `ember-cli` so that the sass is being built during deploy with the rest of `ember-cli-sass`, but I can't figure out how to do it in an automated fashion (e.g. without manually copying files over to `public`).

Using [`ember-auto-import`](https://github.com/ef4/ember-auto-import) seems like a good place to start but it is more tailored towards javascript imports.

I have tried this configuration in `ember-cli-build.js`:

```
    'sassOptions': {
        includePaths: [
            'node_modules/flag-icon-css/sass' // flag-icon.scss
        ]
    },
```

It will add the styles, but it doesn't include the images used in the styles.

I have read [this documentation](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/addons-and-dependencies/), but it doesn't specify something more complicated than a single file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use `ember-cli-sass`:

1. first add it to `includePaths` in your `ember-cli-build.js`

```
new EmberApp({
  sassOptions: {
    includePaths: [
      'node_modules/flag-icon-css/sass'
    ]
  }
});
```

2. use it with `@import "flag-icon";`

Have a look in the [readme](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-cli-sass#example).

now while this will sucessfully add the compiled sass output to your `/assets/app-name.js` there is no automated way to add any kind of assets to your `dist` folder.

In the case of `flag-icon-css` it will just add `background-image: url(../flags/4x3/gr.svg);` to your `dist/assets/app-name.css`, but not add the `svg` itself. You can manually do this with broccolis `Funnel` and `MergeTrees`:

1. install `broccoli-funnnel` and `broccoli-merge-trees`
2. import them in `ember-cli-build.js`:

```
const Funnel = require('broccoli-funnel');
const MergeTrees = require('broccoli-merge-trees');
```

3. use them by replacing `return app.toTree()` in your `ember-cli-build.js` with

```
const flagIcons = Funnel('node_modules/flag-icon-css', { include: ['flags/**/*'] });
return new MergeTrees([app.toTree(), flagIcons]);
```

---

so your entire `ember-cli-build.js` could look like this:

```
'use strict';

const EmberApp = require('ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app');
const Funnel = require('broccoli-funnel');
const MergeTrees = require('broccoli-merge-trees');

module.exports = function(defaults) {
  let app = new EmberApp(defaults, {
    // Add options here
    sassOptions: {
      includePaths: [
        'node_modules/flag-icon-css/sass'
      ]
    }
  });

  const flagIcons = Funnel('node_modules/flag-icon-css', { include: ['flags/**/*'] });
  return new MergeTrees([app.toTree(), flagIcons]);
};
```

---

a short sidenote: I would usually recommend to put assets into the `assets` folder of your output, but in this case this wont work because the `flag-icon-css` expects the `flags` folder to be in the *parent* directory of the `.css`.

Comment: I've tried that (and also `autoImport.webpack`) but then I don't get the related (in this specific case 'flag') images, just the styles. I'll edit that into the question.

Comment: `MergeTrees` is not necessary anymore. I posted the final answer below. I'll accept yours because you took the time to help me and put me on the right track. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I figured this out, but I'm not sure it's the best or easiest way. It has some drawbacks.

```js
const EmberApp = require('ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app')
const Funnel = require('broccoli-funnel')

module.exports = function(defaults) {
    const app = new EmberApp(defaults, {
        'sassOptions': {
            includePaths: [
                'node_modules/flag-icon-css/sass'
            ]
        }
    })

    const flags = new Funnel('node_modules/flag-icon-css/', {
        srcDir: 'flags',
        destDir: '/flags',
    })

    return app.toTree([flags])
}
```

The drawback is that the css image urls are not processed, and hardlinked to `../flags`, so I *have* to funnel them into `/flags`, which is not the convention, as these assets should be compiled into `public/assets/images`.

This is a two-step implementation (or more steps if the npm module would be more complex). It would be preferred to include just the `scss` and have (an) Ember (plugin) automatically fetch the dependent resources.

Comment: Its probably the best solution. I'm not sure if there is anything out there that can automatically resolve all urls in `css/sass`.